# Align a button?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a button to the right, whereas some other text is placed in the same line aligned to the left:

```
<h1 style="display:inline; text-align:left">
<span>somevalue</span>
</h1>
<input type="submit" value="somevalue" style="vertical-align:top; text-align: right"/>
```

Result:
the vertical alignment takes place. the align to the right does *not*.
Does anyone know why? Or a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use float:left and float:right

```
    <h1 style="display:inline; float:left">    
    <span>somevalue</span>
</h1> 
    <input type="submit" value="somevalue" style="vertical-align:top; float: right"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the button inside a div and set the div with right align:

```
<div id="someDiv" style="display:inline; text-align:right">
    <h:commandButton value="somevalue" style="vertical-align:top"/>
</div>
```

Comment: That div will also need display:inline;

Comment: @AndrewBacon Edited the answer. Anyway, the `display:inline` is set by default to HTML elements, but it can improve the answer in this example :)

Comment: A DIV defaults to display:block; , SPAN defaults to display:inline;